# WHS - client does not shutdown after backup

Tags: backup, windows-7, windows-home-server

I have my WHS/Win 7 laptop configured to do automatic backups through the connector.  The backups run just fine every night.  I put my computer in hibernate when I go to bed, it wakes and runs the backups, but then it doesn't go back into hibernate or shutdown.  I'd like to be able to force it to shutdown after the backups are completed.  I don't see a scheduled task in the system for the WHS backups.  Any idea how I can get my laptop to shutdown after the backups are complete?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a scheduled task on the client to shutdown if the computer is idle for more than an hour. It executes `C:\Windows\System32\shutdown.exe` with the argument `/s`. I'm using the Events that WHS creates to trigger my task.

**Triggers**

```
Trigger Settings:
Begin the task: On an event
Log: Application
Source: HomeServer
EventId: 769
Delay Task for: 30 minutes
```

**Conditions**

```
Start the task only if it is idle for: 30 minutes
Wait for idle: do not wait
Stop if the computer ceases to be idle (checked)
REstart if the idle resumes (checked)
```

Comment: why would you do this and not just enable power management features?

Answer (score 1):

Please see [my answer](https://superuser.com/questions/39584/what-is-the-command-to-use-to-put-your-computer-to-sleep-not-hibernate/188708#188708) to this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/17172/can-i-make-my-pc-backup-and-then-sleep-on-demand-with-whs). It offers an alternative solution to the rediculous 'turn on to backup' design of WHS.

- Basically i wrote a script to manually run a backup and then sleep.
- I activate it when I go to bed.
- None of this complete utter nonsense of waking up my machine, or burning the house down.